# Rotate a ggplot2 plot object

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to rotate a complete ggplot object 90°.

I do not wish to use `coord_flip` as this appears to interfere with `scale="free"` and `space="free"` when using facets.

For example:

```
qplot(as.factor(mpg), wt, data=mtcars)+
facet_grid(.~vs + am, scale="free",space="free")
```

[image]

vs

```
qplot(as.factor(mpg), wt, data=mtcars)+
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ ., scale="free",space="free")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

What I would like:

[image]

I would likely need to use `gridExtra`.

Comment: Why do you need to rotate with ggplot2/grid? It's probably easier to rotate in whichever software (e.g., latex or word) you want to use this.

Comment: If you want to rotate a plot within a Rmarkdown document you can simply use the chunk option out.extra='angle=-90' .

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712801/how-to-combine-two-ggplots-with-one-rotated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
print(p, vp=viewport(angle=-90))
```

Comment: The laborious alternative I had found was `grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(angle=-90, width = unit(7, "inches"), height = unit(7, "inches")))  grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)))`

Comment: Good one. You are the gridly-Ace. (I would probably have just printed as "landscape", but I can see the value of being able to send this in knitr or other markup systems.

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie if you have pushed a viewport, you can use `print(p, newpage=FALSE)`. And if for some reason you want to draw a grob explicitly, `ggplotGrob` is a shorter alias.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were expecting?

```
qplot(x=wt, y=as.factor(mpg), data=mtcars) +
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ ., scale="free", space="free")
```

[image: "rotated" plot]

Comment: Yes, but turning the whole plot is what I was looking for.  Thanks.